# Executor Service: SingleThreadExecutor not firing runnable object

Tags: java, concurrency, executorservice

I am trying to execute a runnable object using the Java concurrency package's, ExecutorService SingleThreadExecutor. When I call the execute a command on the new Runnable object it simply steps over it. i.e. the run() method isn't called.

I have stepped through my lines of code using the debugger and can see my SingleThreadExecutor has been created and my Runnable is initialised.

```
public class RunnableDemo {

    public ExecutorService executor;

    public RunnableDemo () {
        this.executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    }

    public void start(){
       executor.execute(new MyRunnable("Hello World"));
    }

   public static void main(String[] args){
        RunnableDemo app = new RunnableDemo();
        app.start();
    }
}

public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
   private String strToPrint;

   public MyRunnable(String parameter) {
       this.strToPrint = parameter;
   }

   public void run() {
      System.out.println(strToPrint);
   }
}
```

And probably self-explanatory but in this scenario, I would expect to see "Hello World" printed to screen. However, the execute/run method doesn't seem to be invoked after the runnable is created.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile, as your constructor has the signature `public runnableDemo()` yet your class name is `RunnableDemo`. Also, the constructor of `MyRunnable` accepts a `Sting` instead of `String`.

Comment: After fixing compilation error mentioned on above comment your code is working fine.

Comment: It's working fine after edit.

Answer (score -1):

Your program is terminating before the executer starts the task.

You have to wait for the executor to finish like this:

```
public class RunnableDemo {

public ExecutorService executor;

public RunnableDemo () {
    this.executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
}

public void start(){
   executor.execute(new MyRunnable("Hello World"));
}

public void awaitTermination(){
  try {
        service.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    RunnableDemo app = new RunnableDemo();
    app.start();
    app.awaitTermination();
}
}

public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
private String strToPrint;

public MyRunnable(String parameter) {
   this.strToPrint = parameter;
}

public void run() {
  System.out.println(strToPrint);
}
}
```

Comment: The `ThreadPoolExecutor` returned by `newSingleThreadExecutor` creates and starts a non-daemon thread as soon as a task is submitted (here with `execute`). The application can't exit until that thread has stopped.